# Magento 2 - Error in order confirm email

Tags: magento2, error, sales-order, order-email

I am unable to find a solution for this error :

```
Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: _store in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml on line 32
```

I am also getting this error in the email :

```
Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Emthemes/everything_default/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/product_base_image.jpg'
    #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(134): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
    #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
    #2 /var/www/html/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
    #3 {main}
```

Below is my Code

```
<?php
    $_item = $block->getItem();
    $_order = $_item->getOrder();
    $_store = $_order->getStore();
    $_imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $_baseImageUrl = $_store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product';
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="item-thumbnail">
            <img src="<?= $_imageHelper->init($_item->getProduct(), 'product_base_image', ['type'=>'product_base_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('120','120')->getUrl();?>" alt="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>">
        </td>
        <td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">
            <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
            <p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
            <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
                <dl class="item-options">
                <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                    <dt><strong><em><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
            <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
                <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
        </td>
        <td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
        <td class="item-price">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())): ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="item-extra">
            <table class="message-gift">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message') ?></h3>
                        <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                        <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: add full code from this file.

Comment: I have added all code please check

Comment: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Emthemes/everything_default/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/product_base_image.jpg'
  This means this file do not exist as per its name and path on source.

Comment: Thank you sir i will check it

Comment: You can get media path as per the answer i posted or if you want to check with you current code, try var_dump($_order->getStore()); & observe what's there if it contains data or not.

Comment: Mark answer as right if its helpful to you, eventually it will help magento community.

Answer (score 1):

Get media path by Dependency Injection

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct( 
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ...
}

public function getMediaUrl()
{
    $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager
                     ->getStore()
                     ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    return $mediaUrl;
}
```

Now call function `getMediaUrl()` in phtml

```
<?php echo $block->getMediaUrl(); ?>
```

Comment: This is how you can get the media url, modify code as per your requirements.

Comment: can you help me on this case: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/321120/86511
Thank you

Comment: its working thank you for help

Comment: Mark answer as right, if it works.