# Magento2 Page jumps to top when click Menu Icon on mobile

Tags: magento2, menu, luma-theme

How to Stop the top menu bar scrolling up the page in website 
I have same issue facing like below website but 
 I am using Porto theme and I have checked with default `luma theme` this issue also coming on `luma theme` also

****`NOTE:`** my header is the sticky header on mobile**

Example : **https://outfitters.com.pk/pages/men**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using css

```
thead {position:fixed; top:0px;}
```

Check this link

http://jsfiddle.net/john_rock/h6hfX/1/

Comment: Thanks for answer but in where i will add css my header is sticky header..

Comment: You can add in active theme - app/design/frontend/proto/theme/css/

Comment: yes but when? header class or body class or after menu open?